# Jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

How to set branch name in variable in Jenkins Pipeline job?
I have Jenins pipeline below which returns null in BRANCH_NAME

```
node{
    def BRANCH_NAME = env.BRANCH_NAME
    echo BRANCH_NAME
}
```

Comment: `env.BRANCH_NAME` is not intrinsically defined in the pipeline, unless (I believe) you are also using the SCM step plugin in the pipeline.

Comment: Not enough information to determine.  We need to see all your code for this pipeline and also screenshots of the configuration screen itself ( specifically the SCM panel and variables panel ). Go to https://<your-jenkins-basename-host>/env-vars.html/ and let us know if you see BRANCH_NAME listed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get branch name through `env.BRANCH_NAME`, your pipeline need to be [Multiple Branch Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/).

```
BRANCH_NAME

For a multibranch project, this will be set to the name of the branch being built, 
for example in case you wish to deploy to production from 
master but not from feature branches; 

if corresponding to some kind of change request, the name is generally arbitrary 
(refer to CHANGE_ID and CHANGE_TARGET).
```